# subprocess.Popen() not waiting for s3 sync command to complete

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, synchronization, subprocess

I am using the `aws s3 sync` command to sync files from s3 to local and perform some operations using python. Since there is no `boto3` implementation of `s3 sync` I am running the cli command using `subprocess.Popen()`. I also tried `.run` but it still doesn't wait for all the files to be downloaded and continues to the next line of code with only a few files downloaded.

My sync function looks like this:

```
    def sync_s3(self, aws_cli_path, s3_path, local_directory, aws_profile):
        print("Running sync command from s3")
        try:
            process = subprocess.Popen([aws_cli_path, "s3", "sync", s3_path, local_directory, "--profile", aws_profile], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
            while process.poll() is None:
                pass    
            stdout, stderr = process.communicate()

            if process.returncode != 0:
                raise Exception(stderr.decode())
            else:
                 print("S3 sync command completed successfully:", stdout.decode())
                 logging.info(f'S3 sync completed successfully: {stdout.decode()}')
        except Exception as e:
            print("Command failed with error:", e)
            logging.critical(f'S3 sync failed: {e}')
            sys.exit(701)
```

Also tried using a `subprocess.run()` but it still doesn't wait for the files to be downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run), `subprocess.run()` should wait for the command to complete.  Thus, you should be okay with:

```
process = subprocess.run([aws_cli_path, "s3", "sync", s3_path, local_directory, "--profile", aws_profile], capture_output=True)

if process.returncode != 0:
    raise Exception(process.stderr.decode())
else:
    print("S3 sync command completed successfully:", process.stdout.decode())
    logging.info(f'S3 sync completed successfully: {process.stdout.decode()}')
```

Works perfectly on my end.